# TS declaration: How is it possible to import variable, when it has not been prefixed with export keyword

Tags: typescript

```
//file-a.d.ts
declare const a: number;

export declare const b: number;

//file-b.ts
import { a, b } from './file-a';
```

How could I import `a` in file-b.ts when I have not tagged the export keyword in the declarations in file-a.d.ts?

I am using Typescript 3.5.3.

*If this was added in some later typescript version, please provide the link.*

Comment: You can't.  If it's not exported, you can't import it.

Comment: @user2740650 I just did, hence I post the question. I am using Typescript 3.5.3. Also, note that file-a.d.ts is a declaration file.

Comment: Oh, you didn't actually say that you'd tried it!  It looked like you were wondering how to do it.  I suspect then that there's some sort of stale results happening in your case since it shouldn't be possible.  If you try to run the resulting JS, you'll probably get a runtime exception about the missing export.

Comment: file-a.d.ts is a declaration file, i don't know what you mean by 'stale result'. Declaration file just helps for design time type safety, and has no effect on resulting JS. Additionally, i did do "Restart TS Server" in VS code, and this still persists.

Comment: Yes I know .d.ts is a declaration file, but I thought it had been generated by a compiler, and by "stale" I meant maybe it was out of date with respect to whatever source file was used to generate it.  But if you are hand-coding it, I have no idea if it's valid or not :-) .  Still, eventually you'll end up trying to run JS, and as I said it should fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I import a in file-b.ts when I have not tagged the export keyword in the declarations in file-a.d.ts?

you cannot ES6 `import` something that isn't `export`ed. < Period.

Comment: The other person who commented in the question above had similar response. Actually I was able to and thus this question. I am using Typescript 3.5.3. Also, note that file-a.d.ts is a declaration file.

Comment: @zzxoto You were able to but didn't explain how you did it? That really doesn't make sense, you should listen to what others are saying and improve your question, right now it doesn't really make sense